# How to prevent iphone notch from overlapping content in bookmarked desktop app?

Tags: flutter

I'm using SafeArea to display a bottom navigation bar :

```
SafeArea(
      child: ScaffoldMessenger(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: _tabs[index],
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
            showUnselectedLabels: true,
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today), label: "Agenda"),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.people), label: "Patients"),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet), label: "Comptes"),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.settings), label: "Réglages"),
            ],
            currentIndex: index,
            onTap: (i) => context.read(navigationIndexProvider).index = i,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

When bookmarked on iphone desktop, the safe area does not prevent the notch from overlapping the bottom navbar.

Here is the result :

[image]

How to properly prevent notch from overlapping the bottom bar ?

Answer (score 1):

I think since you're using bottomNavigationBar, the SafeArea should not be wrapped around Scaffold. It should be wrapped by Scaffold like this:

```
Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(child:
_tabs[index] ...
```

I think you should only wrap Scaffold with SafeArea when you're not using any kind of bottomNavigationBar

Answer (score 0):

In SAFEAREA widget there is an argument -bottom
Set this bottom either true or false.

SafeArea(
bottom:true,
child:ScaffoldMessanger()
)

I don't remember the correct one, you can check both and let us know which one  works for you.

Comment: I saw this but its default value is already true

Comment: Set it to false then,

Comment: It might be related to the fact that it's a flutter web app placed as a shortcut on the iphone desktop, and not a real iphone app.